# getting the response from a route

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, in the following example, how can I assign the json response from the route `/api/topics` to my `$topics` variable in my backend?

API:

```
Route::get( '/api/topics', function()
{
    return Topic::all();
});
```

Backend:

```
Route::get( '/backend/topics', function()
{
    $topics = // call to route /api/topics goes here;

    return View::make( 'backend.topics' )->with( array( 'topics' => $topics ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call your URL, you won't have a JSON object in return, but a JSON String, that you need to decode. To retrieve the content of your page, you can simply use file_get_contents.

```php
Route::get( '/backend/topics', function()
{
    $topics = file_get_contents('/api/topics');
    // you may test if $topics !== FALSE
    $topics = json_decode($topics);

    return View::make( 'backend.topics' )->with( array( 'topics' => $topics ) );
});
```

This is the simple way. You may want to use a PHP REST Client to handle HTTP status code, ect...

Comment: Well, in my frontend I do everything with AngularJS. I was just quickly throwing together this backend and then noticed that I don't actually know how to get the result without using Angular ;)